# Стоит ли писать свою библиотеку по элементарной математике?

Tags: математика, c++

У меня в знаниях математики есть большие пробелы. Стоит ли писать свои функции-алгоритмы, которых не запоминаешь, чтоб упростить жизнь и заодно подтянуть начальные классы.

Comment: Ради
> заодно подтянуть начальные классы
Однозначно стоит, любое "повторение - мать учения"

Comment: Решать задачи любым доступным способом (в том числе и написанием библиотек) - это всегда хорошо. Но вот я только смутно себе представляю, какие алгоритмы будете подтягивать с начальных классов. Умножение столбиком?

Comment: Ага, например, разложение числа на множители и дальше все по алгебре и высшей математике, множества и т.п.
_____
Сейчас времени больше свободного стало. Раньше не было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вашей задачей и конечной целью является "подтягивание" знаний по математике, и вы хотите написать собственные реализации математических функций, то почему бы и нет.